# wp footer appearing in sidebar

Tags: wordpress, image, footer, sidebar

I am having a problem doing a site Im building for my mum with the right side bar/footer on the 'About Tara' page (http://www.taranoone.ie/about-tara/).  Im putting in Logo img's into the right side bar, two weird things are happening.

1) The footer seems to have become part of the right side bar now on that page.
2) The widget shows up on chrome but on safari and firefox only the first img in the widget shows up.

Can someone help?

Comment: The footer isn't showing in the sidebar for me...Please include your HTML markup, so that we can help you, and so that this question remains useful in the future.

Comment: This is more an HTML/CSS problem than WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see the footer in the sidebar because in your HTML the footer is inside the sidebar.

If you open the browser inspector (in PC/Chrome Ctrl + Shift + i), you can see that the div `.hc_footer_widget_area` is inside the div `.hc_sidebar`

---

About the widgets, you have also incorrect HTML. Review your code, you seem to forget to close some tags.

Comment: ThemesCreator, thank you. I had been moving the code around and in the process had lost the closing tags on the img's somewhere. 

In hind sight this question is not useful as the answer was a silly over sight, should I just delete it?

Comment: Maybe, like you side I don't think it will help anyone more but I am not an expert in how Stackoverflow works. Meanwhile you can accept my answer as correct :)

Comment: Il leave it up as you took the time to answer and you found the solution. Thanks again.